# powershell "-match" not matching as hoped, seeking advice

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a need to rename files and folders based on a date anywhere in the name/folder string, front/middle/end.

The date formats can be like:

- DD-MM-YYYY
- D-M-YYYY
- D-MM-YYYY
- DD-M-YYYY
- YYYY-MM-DD
- YYYY-M-D
- YYYY-MM-D
- YYYY-M-DD

and intra-date separators can be any of these 3 characters

- - (dash)
- _ (underscore)
- . (period)

I had thought the match strings below (provided by ChatGPT) would do the trick but no.
It only matches if the date is at the start of a string.

```
$fileName = "Youghusband Friends 2012-12-14 003.jpg"
    if ($fileName -match  '^(\d{1,2}|\d{2})[-_.](\d{1,2}|\d{2})[-_.](\d{4})(.*)$') {
        $matchedPart = $matches[0]
        Write-Host "FILE_MATCH_C (c) ALL: '$fileName'       Matched Part: '$matchedPart'     matches[1..3]='$matches[1..3]'"
    } elseif ($fileName -match '^(\d{4})[-_.](\d{1,2}|\d{2})[-_.](\d{1,2}|\d{2})(.*)$') {
        $matchedPart = $matches[0]
        Write-Host "FILE_MATCH_D (d) ALL: '$fileName'       Matched Part: '$matchedPart'     matches[1..3]='$matches[1..3]'"
    } else {
        Write-Host "FILE_NO_MATCH: '$fileName'"
    }
```

Result:

```
FILE_NO_MATCH: 'Youghusband Friends 2012-12-14 003.jpg'
```

What match strings would fix it ? (and why)

Thanks

Comment: You wrote in your question: _It only matches if the date is at the start of a string_ Obviously, because of the `^` character. Do you know the purpose of this metacharacter in a regular expression?

Comment: Are those 8 [date] formats the only possible ones? Or are there others?

Comment: They are the only ones I know of in an archive of 28,000 family pics  No I did not know its purpose, the string was provided by ChatGPT and I took it at face value.
 }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clear issue with your regex is the use of `^` (start of the line) and `$` (end of the line) instead of using word boundaries (`\b`). Here is how you could approach your code with a single regex:

```bash
$re = '(?x)
\b(?:
    (?<day>[0-9]{1,2})[-_.]
    (?<month>[0-9]{1,2})[-_.]
    (?<year>[0-9]{4})
  |
    (?<year>[0-9]{4})[-_.]
    (?<month>[0-9]{1,2})[-_.]
    (?<day>[0-9]{1,2})
)\b'

$fileName = 'Youghusband Friends 2012-12-14 003.jpg'

if ($fileName -match $re) {
    # if you want to have it as a datetime instace, here you can do:
    # [datetime]::new($Matches['year'], $Matches['month'], $Matches['day'])

    [pscustomobject]@{
        date  = $Matches[0]
        year  = $Matches['year']
        month = $Matches['month']
        day   = $Matches['day']
    }
}
else {
    Write-Host "FILE_NO_MATCH: '$fileName'"
}
```

See https://regex101.com/r/R0EkUj/1 for regex details.

Comment: Thank you very much ! That did the trick very nicely. I had not come across anything like that before.

Comment: A followup; given it's found, how to return the original string with it removed ?

Comment: @hydra3333 do you mean the extracted date as a whole? If so, you can use `$Matches[0]`

Comment: OK like this I guess: $matched_text = $Matches[0]
  $newFileName = $newFileName -replace $matched_text, "" Thanks!